# What is the difference in meaning between 'was doing' and 'did' in American English?

Tags: meaning

I found American use a lot of 'was doing' expression than English speakers from other countries.

I am wondering is there any difference of meaning in these two expressions? Grammatically speaking, of course, they are different. But I think American just take them as the same in daily speakings.

> I was doing a lot of road trips in California.
>
> I did a lot of road trips in California.

Comment: [grammatically speaking or grammar-wise and everyday speech] **This usage is not marked as American at all**. I was doing a lot of drinking in those days. [down at the pub]. A Brit could say that as could an AmE speaker. No one sees those two as the same thing in native English speech. I can guarantee you that.

Comment: I think you're mistaken in thinking *Americans* are particularly likely to favour Past Continuous over Simple Past. The only "linguistic community" I know of associated with overuse of continuous participles is *Indian English* (where it's an archetypal "shibboleth" marking IE speakers out from "mainstream" Anglophones).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Trump's president now. All logic and meaning has officially disappeared from American English.

Comment: @DavidM: That's "all logic and meaning" in the *anti-* Trump camp. My understanding is the reason so many people are still in the *pro-* Trump camp is that he's that very rare thing in modern democratic politics - a leader who both says what he means *and* means what he says (it's up to the voters whether they agree with him, but at least they can see what he stands for).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the tense of the verb to do.

*I did* is the simple past.

*I was doing* is the imperfect.

*I had done* is the past perfect.

As in other languages, all convey a sense of past action. But the meaning of each is slightly different.

*I did* implies a past action that has finished in a specified time frame.

> I did a lot of road trips in 1973

*I was doing* implies it was an unspecified amount of time or simulataneous action.

> I was doing a lot of road trips back when I worked for IBM.

*I had done* means it was already done at that time.

> I had done a lot of road trips by the time I went on this trip.

Answer (score 1):

"I did" is the "simple past" form. We use the simple past to express the idea that an action started and finished at a specific time in the past.

Here is a good example -

> Sarah says, "I **was doing** my homework and my friend called."
>   Rachel says, "I **did** my homework and my friend called."

This means that Rachel finished her homework, but Sarah did not finish her homework. The "was doing" means that something was still going on, that it was interrupted or that it never finished.

Another example -

> We worked from 9 am to 5 pm yesterday.

is best as a simple statement of fact. But you could use:

> We were working from 9:00 to 5:00 yesterday. Around 1:00 the power went out.

if you are describing other things that were going on at that time.